# Binary variable constraint for condition

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I am trying to solve the following task:
If $x=1$ or $y=0$ then $z=0$

My approach:

If $z=0$ then $x+y \le 2 + Mz \implies x+y \le 2+2z \quad$
where $M = 2$

If $z=1$ then $x+y=1 \\
\implies 
x+y \le 1, \quad x+y \ge 1 - M(1-z) \\
\implies x+y \ge z$

where $M = 1$

I already tried to add the constraint:
$y-x \ge 0$ to ensure that combination $x=1, y=0, z=1$ should be satisfied and combination $x=1, y=0, z=1$ should be not satisfied.

But then the combination $x=1, y=0, z=0$ isn’t satisfied, although it should be.

In 1 combination the sum of $x+y = 2$.

I would be grateful for any hints regarding the task or showing where my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via conjunctive normal form,
$$
(x \lor \lnot y) \implies \lnot z \\
\lnot (x \lor \lnot y) \lor \lnot z \\
(\lnot x \land y) \lor \lnot z \\
(\lnot x \lor \lnot z) \land (y \lor \lnot z) \\
((1 - x) + (1 - z) \ge 1) \land (y + (1 - z) \ge 1) \\
(x + z \le 1) \land (y \ge z)
$$

Comment: is there any problem to write $x+z \leq 1$ as $x+z = 1$?

Comment: @A.Omidi That is too strong. For example, it would mistakenly cut off $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: many thanks. 

Comment: The conjunctive normal form derivation is a powerful and general approach, but it can be obscure in simple cases. Here, the correctness of the linear reformulation is clearer if you write it as $z\leq (1-x)$ and $z\leq y$.

Comment: @4er Indeed, your rewrite arises immediately from the contrapositive $z \implies (\lnot x \land y)$.